# How to display values in a table after join two table of a database using angular.js and php

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have one doubt; I want to display some value in a table and those values will fetch from two table of a DB using angular.js and PHP. Let me to explain my code first.

**dept.html**:

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>
<th>Dept Name</th>
<th>Short Name</th>
<th>HOD</th>
<th>No of Faculty</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

My controller file code is given below.

```
$scope.listOfDeptData=[];
    var datas='';
    $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/princpaldept/getDeptData.php",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    });
```

**getDeptData.php**:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "******", "go_fasto");
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from db_department  order by dept_id desc");
$data = array();
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($data);
```

I added the DB structure below.

**db_user**:

```
user_id    roll_id  user_type    user_name  mob_name  user_status  dept_id

 1           2         3         Rahul      99*****     1            15

 2           2        3          Raj        98*****     1            16
```

**db_department**:

```
dept_id   dept_name     short_name     login_name

 15       Civil           civil         civil123

 16       Mechanical       Mech         mech123
```

**db_roll**

```
roll_id    roll

1         Principal

2         HOD

3         Professor
```

Here my requirement is the first 2 data(`dept name,short name`) will fetch from `db_department` and by using each `dept_id` the No of faculty will fetch from `db_user` table  and using same `dept_id and role_id=2` HOD will fetch from `db_user` table and finally display the data in table. Please help me.

Comment: Forget anuglar and php this has nothing to do with that. What you need is a mysql inner join https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: please add database structure with some values.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju : I added the DB structure.